# Representation of number sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

can this array of numbers sequence be represented in less characters (excluding whitespace) than this?

```
i = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,0,4,8,6,4,2];
```

(52 chars)

or a function i which returns the same values in under 52 chars

the aim is to reduce the number of characters used to represent the code.

Comment: If it’s just numbers between 0 and 9: `"012345678036147258048642"`. For other bases you could use a different encoding.

Comment: If you can explain how this bit works, in the bigger picture, we might be able to provide a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i='012345678036147258048642'.split('');

Comment: thats good but returns a character array rather than an integer array

Comment: If looping through this array, adding `parseInt()` will still be 49 characters ;)

Comment: yeah but parseInt will be repeated multiple times, i have more than one reference to i

Comment: is there any way to cast the character array to an integer array in concise code?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, what about using `+` instead of `parseInt()`? ;-)

Comment: Good idea, but rather `*1`, because `+` will concatenate two chars into string. And still it only applies when looping through array to have it in one place for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

***I don't necessarily recommend this***... (because I don't think you should "wreck" the String object) but in theory *you could* do this:

```
<script>
  String.prototype.toNumericalArray = function(){
    var arr = this.split('');
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      arr[i] = 0+i;
    }
    return arr;
  }
</script>
```

Then when you want it, all you need is:

```
<script>
  s='012345678036147258048642';
  n = s.toNumericalArray();
  alert(typeof(n[3]));//number
  alert(typeof(n[7]));//number
  alert(typeof(n[9]));//number
</script>
```

And if you are really worried about the number of characters, you can minify all the variables / method name

```
i='012345678036147258048642'.x();
```

(thus if you exclude the initial prototype, any future calls would be 33 characters (for the same size list))

Answer (score 1):

I would always go with the comma separated array,

it's less overhead than any conversion process.

But the idea of a quick method to turn a string of digits

into an array of numbers appealed to my evil twin...

```
String.prototype.dA= function digitArray(){
    return eval('['+this.replace(/(\d)/g,'+$1,')+']');
}
```

**i='012345678036147258048642'.dA();** (34 characters)

```
// test i
for(var j= 0, L= i.length; j<L;j++){
    i[j]= i[j]+' ('+typeof i[j]+')';
}
i.join(', ')
```

/*  returned value:
0 (number), 1 (number), 2 (number), 3 (number), 4 (number), 5 (number), 6 (number), 7 (number), 8 (number), 0 (number), 3 (number), 6 (number), 1 (number), 4 (number), 7 (number), 2 (number), 5 (number), 8 (number), 0 (number), 4 (number), 8 (number), 6 (number), 4 (number), 2 (number)
*/